# Context menu not being loaded by extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm following this tutorial on how to create a context menu when a user right clicks on selected text, the menu offers the user the option to send the text to a server:

http://vikku.info/programming/chrome-extension/get-selected-text-send-to-web-server-in-chrome-extension-communicate-between-content-script-and-background-page.htm#Comments

Here are the files:

The *myscript.js* file:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(event)
{

  var sel = window.getSelection().toString();
  alert('selection is '+sel)

  if(sel.length)
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({'message':'setText','data': sel},function(response){})
})
```

The *background.html* file:

```
<script>

var seltext = null;

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
  switch(request.message)
  {
    case 'setText':
      window.seltext = request.data
    break;

    default:
      sendResponse({data: 'Invalid arguments'});
    break;
  }
});


function savetext(info,tab)
{
  var jax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  jax.open("POST","http://localhost/text/");
  jax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  jax.send("text="+seltext);
  jax.onreadystatechange = function() { if(jax.readyState==4) { alert(jax.responseText);  }}
}

alert('here')
var contexts = ["selection"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++)
{
  var context = contexts[i];
  chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Send to Server", "contexts":[context], "onclick": savetext});
}

</script>
```

The *manifest.json* file:

```
<script>

var seltext = null;

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
  switch(request.message)
  {
    case 'setText':
      window.seltext = request.data
    break;

    default:
      sendResponse({data: 'Invalid arguments'});
    break;
  }
});


function savetext(info,tab)
{
  var jax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  jax.open("POST","http://localhost/text/");
  jax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  jax.send("text="+seltext);
  jax.onreadystatechange = function() { if(jax.readyState==4) { alert(jax.responseText);  }}
}

alert('here')
var contexts = ["selection"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++)
{
  var context = contexts[i];
  chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Send to Server", "contexts":[context], "onclick": savetext});
}

</script>
```

The *popup.html* file:

```
<body>
Just a sample popup
</body>
```

---

In *myscript.js* the function `document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(event)` is called every time a `mouseup` event is fired ed but I think this should be called if the user decides to send the request to the server. The context menu should be fired when the user right clicks selected text but I don't know why this is occurring? I needed to update the manifest version to 2.

Comment: Could you fix your code?  You have `manifest.json` pointing to a script tag.  And `background.html` pointing to a script tag as well (which should be `background.js`).

Comment: What do you mean by "I think this should be called if the user decides to send the request to the server"? The [`mouseup` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseup) is defined by http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseup and doesn't involve asking the user anything. Also, ["background_page" doesn't exist in modern extensions.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion#manifest-v1-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i understood that  your problem is that context menu is not firing... for that you need to do small changes to your manifest

1. add manifest vesrion as 2
2. change background_page as background which is a key and value as {scripts:["background.js"]}
3. create a new javascript file with name as background.js and copy the script tag which is there in background html.i added manifest and javascript. let me know if you found any difficulty.

manifest:

```
{
"name": "Word Reminder",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Word Reminder.",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "images/stick-man1.gif",
"popup":"popup.html"
},

"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
"js": ["js/myscript.js"]
}
],

"permissions": [
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*",
"contextMenus",
"tabs"
],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src    'self'"

}
```

background.js(new file in the same folder should contain below code):

```
var seltext = null;

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
switch(request.message)
{
    case 'setText':
        window.seltext = request.data
    break;

    default:
        sendResponse({data: 'Invalid arguments'});
    break;
}
});


function savetext(info,tab)
{
var jax = new XMLHttpRequest();
jax.open("POST","http://localhost/text/");
jax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
jax.send("text="+seltext);
jax.onreadystatechange = function() { if(jax.readyState==4) {     alert(jax.responseText);  }}
}

var contexts = ["selection"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++)
{
var context = contexts[i];
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Send to Server", "contexts":[context], "onclick": savetext});  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know, if i got you right...the user select text, press the right mouse button and than you want to do "something"...

try this:

'get the right mouse click

```
window.oncontextmenu = function ()
{
    showSelection();  // call a function or do something here
    return false;     // cancel the default right click mouse menu (necessary)
}
```

'in the function get the selected text and do something

```
function showSelection()
{
    var sel = window.getSelection().toString();
    alert('selection is '+sel);
    .....
}
```